# this.props becomes undefined after first dispatch action from the component ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using a third party component in my react component and I am using redux flow for state management.

Customer Component

```
class Customer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); //This works fine and props are correct
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <ThirdPartyComponent
           eventHandlers={
            new Map([
              [
                "loaded",
                function () {
                 //This is the second action call but this.props becomes undefined at this stage after
                 //the first action of getCustomerObject is called. Not sure why? This is the problem 
                 this.props.actions.handleExtraFunctionality();
                },
              ],
          getCustomer={(customerObject) => {
           //This is the first action call and it works which updates the state
            this.props.actions.getCustomerObject(customerObject);
          }}
        />
      </>
    );
  }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state;
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      handleExtraFunctionality: bindActionCreators(
        customerActions.handleExtraFunctionality,
        dispatch
      ),
      getCustomerObject: bindActionCreators(
        customerActions.getCustomerObject,
        dispatch
      ),
    },
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Customer);
```

Actions

```
function getCustomer(customer) {
  return { type: types.GET_CUSTOMER, customer};
}
```

I am trying to call second action after the first action but this.props becomes undefined after the first call is completed. I am not sure why? Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried using a "fat-arrow" function inside your map? I think this is a scoping issue. Specifically, try replacing `function() { this.props.actions.handleExtraFunctionality(); }` with `() => this.props.actions.handleExtraFunctionality(); }`.

Comment: try console.log(this) in the function of `ThirdPartyComponent`

Comment: @WilliamLewis Is there a way to pass the state into handleExtraFunctionality() which we get from the first action. How can I get something from the state in react Actions?

Comment: @LearnAspNet, typically if you want to pass some part of your state into a component, you include it as a prop by way of `mapStateToProps`. Then, whenever it is updated, your component will re-render and it will have access to the updated value in the corresponding prop. You can then pass this value to your `handleExtraFunctionality` function.

Comment: @WilliamLewis I am very new to React and redux. Can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197971/redux-in-react-to-call-multiple-dispatch-functions

Comment: @WilliamLewis I have one component which is above, then I am triggering set of functions that will call an API, manipulate the data, update the state and other extra things so I would like to chain multiple dispatch actions and use the result of first dispatch action to call next function or how can I get state data inside the action

Comment: @LearnAspNet, there are many ways you could go about doing this, but it might be worth looking into some sort of middleware to help keep this organized. I can highly recommend [`redux-saga`](https://redux-saga.js.org/). There is a bit of a learning curve involved, but it presents a truly neat way of thinking about interacting asynchronous processes like you describe.

Comment: @WilliamLewis I am already using thunks and I am bit familiar with it. Are you able to answer the other question I posted so I have an example to follow?

Comment: @WilliamLewis Hey, how can I pass the state or get state from the global store in different actions. So I am calling an action which calls another function which needs some data from the global store so how can the second function get data from the global store?