# Redux in React to call multiple dispatch functions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an index.js which calls an action. Once it calls an action I want to trigger multiple dispatch actions inside that action. Index.js calls handLoadCustomers which will dispatch loadCustomers function which calls an API and dispatches another function to store customers in the state.

Once that is done, call comes back to handleLoadCustomers where I want to use customers from the first
call and then dispatch another action of handleExtraCustomerLoads with those customers which will
call another functions/actions. How can I do that in React Redux?

```
export function handleLoadCustomers() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(loadCustomers())
      .then((customers) => {
        dispatch(handleExtraCustomerLoads(customers));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      })
      .then((newCustomers) => {
        dispatch(handlePageLoadSuccess(newCustomers));
      });
  };



export function loadCustomers() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return getCustomers()
      .then((customers) => {
        dispatch(loadCustomerSuccess(customers));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  };
}
```

customers after the loadCustomers is empty and it does not dispatch handleExtraCustomerLoads function at all

Comment: Yeah, so what actually's not working?

Comment: @k-wasilewski customers after the loadCustomers is empty and it does not dispatch handleExtraCustomerLoads function at all

Comment: Instead of returning `getCustomers`, dispatch it

Comment: `dispatch(loadCustomers())` is not a promise that why this not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the return value of your action but you can wait for it to finish and select the result from the state (I assume the action will write data you need to the store).

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = {
  customers: [],
  extra: [],
};
//api
const getCustomers = () => Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3]);
//action types
const CUSTOMERS_SUCCESS = 'CUSTOMERS_SUCCESS';
const EXTRA = 'EXTRA';
//action creators
const loadCustomerSuccess = (customers) => ({
  type: CUSTOMERS_SUCCESS,
  payload: customers,
});
const handleExtraCustomerLoads = (extra) => ({
  type: EXTRA,
  payload: extra,
});
function handleLoadCustomers() {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch(loadCustomers()).then(() => {
      const customers = selectCustomers(getState());
      dispatch(handleExtraCustomerLoads(customers));
    });
  };
}
function loadCustomers() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return getCustomers()
      .then((customers) => {
        //you need to return the value here
        return dispatch(loadCustomerSuccess(customers));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  };
}

const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === CUSTOMERS_SUCCESS) {
    return { ...state, customers: payload };
  }
  if (type === EXTRA) {
    return { ...state, extra: payload };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectCustomers = (state) => state.customers;
const selectExtra = (state) => state.extra;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware((store) => (next) => (action) =>
      //diy thunk
      typeof action === 'function'
        ? action(store.dispatch, store.getState)
        : next(action)
    )
  )
);
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const customers = useSelector(selectCustomers);
  const extra = useSelector(selectExtra);
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => dispatch(handleLoadCustomers())}
      >
        load customers
      </button>
      <pre>
        {JSON.stringify({ customers, extra }, undefined, 2)}
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```